# How to distinguish identical parts of a string?

Tags: string, kotlin

So I'm working on a social network as a side project and I've faced the following issue: while mentioning two different users with identical names I can't distinguish them from one another. Here's what I'm doing:

```
fun String.transformMentionForBackend(mentions: List<Mention>): String {
    var result = this
    if (mentions.isNotEmpty()) {
        for (mention in mentions.distinctBy{ Pair(it.id, it.name) }) {
            result = result.replace(mention.name, getMentionTag(mention.id, mention.name))
        }
    }
    return result
}

private fun getMentionTag(id: Int, name: String): String {
    return "<mention id=\"$id\">@$name</mention>"
}
```

This works fine until I want to mention my uncle John Smith `(id: 100, name: John Smith)` and my roommate John Smith `(id:200, name: John Smith)` in the same post or comment, since it `replace()` replaces all occurrences of `mention.name`. I thought of using `replaceFirst()` or `replaceLast()`, but it will just put the tag twice on the first or last name respectively. I tried reading the documentation about Strings, but couldn't really find anything helpful there. What's the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: How do you expect to know which `John Smith` in the original string should be replaced by the mention with id 100, and which should be replaced by the mention with id 200? I mean it's not only about the replacement problem, there is a more fundamental problem in the design: some kind of metadata should be there to know which name was actually auto-completed or whatnot by the user who produced the message in the first place.

Comment: If the `mentions` argument is actually that metadata about the list of mentions used in the message, and it is supposed to be matched by following the order in the list, then it should probably not use `distinctBy` as otherwise you're shifting indices if the same person is mentioned multiple times

Comment: Adding to what @Joffrey said, it is usually a bad idea to scan through a regular string (without any markings) and "guess" what is the meaning of its specific parts. What if the user would write "John Smith" without mentioning anyone? If you are in the position that the only thing you have is a flat string of words, then it means you already lost some important information in the code earlier. Now you can only guess what was this missing information. You need to preserve this info while mentioning.

Comment: Mmm, all of which is implied by the very title of the question. If two things are identical, then you _can't_ distinguish them — by definition!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments posted on the question, I realized I needed something else to distinguish two different mentions with identical names from one another.

What I ended up doing was a for loop, which iterates through the list of mentions by list id (0,1,2 etc.) and only for the first match it replaced the name with a full tag.

It does feel a bit hacky, but I haven't really been able to think of anything else.